# Team scrambler VueJs

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I wanted to do a very little project of a team scrambler. There are two teams of 5 players. Each player has a unique color (in his team) from a limited pool. You can use 2 actions :

- Scramble the teams which mix all players between the two teams
- Request new color for a team which reassign new color for each player of this team

At first, I tried to place players inside an array that I shuffled but since VueJs cannot detect a change on array reassignment natively it ends complicating the code way too much.

So I end up with this solution ([Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/scrambler-rtzoy?file=/pages/index.vue:0-4481) for better readability) where I added a position property in my players :

```
<template>
  <div class="container mx-auto">
    <!-- header -->
    <div class="my-4 flex flex-row justify-center space-x-4">
      <button class="btn btn-red" @click="scrambleTeam1Colors">Color 1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-red" @click="scrambleTeams">SCRAMBLE</button>
      <button class="btn btn-red" @click="scrambleTeam2Colors">Color 2</button>
    </div>
    <!-- teams -->
    <div class="my-2 flex flex-row justify-between">
      <!-- team 1 -->
      <div class="w-2/5 flex flex-col space-y-px">
        <div class="flex att-title items-center">
          <h3 class="flex-grow text-center">Team 1</h3>
        </div>
        <Player v-for="player in team1" :key="player.id" :player="player"/>
      </div>
      <div class="w-1/5"/>
      <!-- team 2 -->
      <div class="w-2/5 flex flex-col space-y-px">
        <div class="flex def-title items-center">
          <h3 class="flex-grow text-center">Team 2</h3>
        </div>
        <Player v-for="player in team2" :key="player.id" :player="player"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Player from "@/components/Player.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Player
  },
  data() {
    return {
      player1: {
        id: 1,
        name: "Player 1",
        color: "red",
        position: 0
      },
      player2: {
        id: 2,
        name: "Player 2",
        color: "blue",
        position: 1
      },
      player3: {
        id: 3,
        name: "Player 3",
        color: "green",
        position: 2
      },
      player4: {
        id: 4,
        name: "Player 4",
        color: "orange",
        position: 3
      },
      player5: {
        id: 5,
        name: "Player 5",
        color: "indigo",
        position: 4
      },
      player6: {
        id: 6,
        name: "Player 6",
        color: "red",
        position: 5
      },
      player7: {
        id: 7,
        name: "Player 7",
        color: "blue",
        position: 6
      },
      player8: {
        id: 8,
        name: "Player 8",
        color: "green",
        position: 7
      },
      player9: {
        id: 9,
        name: "Player 9",
        color: "orange",
        position: 8
      },
      player10: {
        id: 10,
        name: "Player 10",
        color: "indigo",
        position: 9
      },
      colors: [
        "red",
        "blue",
        "green",
        "orange",
        "indigo",
        "yellow",
        "teal",
        "purple",
        "pink"
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    players() {
      return [
        this.player1,
        this.player2,
        this.player3,
        this.player4,
        this.player5,
        this.player6,
        this.player7,
        this.player8,
        this.player9,
        this.player10
      ];
    },
    team1() {
      return this.players.filter(player => player.position < 5);
    },
    team2() {
      return this.players.filter(player => player.position > 4);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    scrambleTeams() {
      let positionsToAssign = Array.from(Array(10).keys());
      positionsToAssign = this.shuffle(positionsToAssign);
      this.players.forEach(
        player => (player.position = positionsToAssign.pop())
      );
      this.scrambleTeam1Colors();
      this.scrambleTeam2Colors();
    },
    scrambleTeam1Colors() {
      let colorsToAssign = this.shuffle([...this.colors]);
      this.team1.forEach(player => (player.color = colorsToAssign.pop()));
    },
    scrambleTeam2Colors() {
      let colorsToAssign = this.shuffle([...this.colors]);
      this.team2.forEach(player => (player.color = colorsToAssign.pop()));
    },
    shuffle(array) {
      let currentIndex = array.length;
      let temporaryValue;
      let randomIndex;

      // While there remain elements to shuffle...
      while (currentIndex !== 0) {
        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
      }

      return array;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="postcss" scoped>
.att-title {
  @apply font-bold bg-red-400 text-white;
}

.def-title {
  @apply font-bold bg-teal-400 text-white;
}

.btn {
  @apply font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded;
}

.btn-red {
  @apply bg-red-500 text-white;
}

.btn-red:hover {
  @apply bg-red-700;
}
</style>
```

Since I am not really experienced in either javascript or vuejs I was wondering if I was missing a way easier way to manage my pool of players and the shuffling. Also, is there an alternative to declaring a computed for my array "players".

Note: The shuffle method is just an algorithm I copied so it is not part of the review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Overall assessment

For a beginner this is a great start. The use of computed properties is nice- especially with the filtering of players into teams. The selection of colors are ascetically pleasing.

## Suggestions

### UI

#### Button Labels

The labels on the top three buttons are *Color 1*, *SCRAMBLE* and *Color 2*, yet it seems that all three lead to some sort of scramble effect. For the first and last buttons it might make sense to each label contain the word *Scramble*, or else abstract the word *Scramble* out into a parent container - e.g.

```html
<link href="//unpkg.com/tailwindcss@0.5.2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<fieldset>
  <legend>Scramble</legend>
  <button class="btn bg-red text-white rounded-full p-2">Team 1</button>
  <button class="btn bg-red text-white rounded-full p-2">Both Teams</button>
  <button class="btn bg-red text-white rounded-full p-2">Team 2</button>
</fieldset>
```

#### Spacing between player squares and labels

It would be wise to add some spacing between the squares and the player labels:

[image: screenshot with arrow]

### JavaScript / VueJS

#### use `const` as default

It is wise to use `const` for declaring variables to avoid accidental re-assignment (e.g. `colorsToAssign` in `scrambleTeam1Colors()` and `scrambleTeam2Colors()`. Then when re-assignment is deemed necessary use `let` - e.g. `positionsToAssign` in `scrambleTeams`.

#### Setting up `data`

The values setup in `data` are a bit redundant. A `for` loop could be used for that:

```
data() {
  const data = {
    players: [],
    colors
  };
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    data.players.push({
      id: i + 1,
      name: "Player " + i,
      color: colors[(i - 1) % 5],
      position: i - 1
    });
  }
  return data;
},
```

where `colors` is moved out above the `export default` statement. This allows the `players` section of `computed` to be removed completely.

#### spreading items into an array

Instead of calling `Array.from()` - e.g.

> ```
> let positionsToAssign = Array.from(Array(10).keys());
> ```

the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) can be used for the same result, without the need to call a function:

```
let positionsToAssign = [...Array(10).keys()];
```

#### Swapping values

instead of this

> ```
> temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
> array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
> array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
> ```

One could use [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to [swap variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Swapping_variables)

```
[array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]] = [array[currentIndex],  array[randomIndex]];
```

However [it seems that is slower than other techniques](https://jsperf.com/swap-array-vs-variable/9) even though the V8 blog claims "*Once we unblocked escape analysis to eliminate all temporary allocation, array destructuring with a temporary array is as fast as a sequence of assignments.*"<sup>[1](https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-68#performance)</sup>. There is a "hack" suggested in [this SO answer by showdev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16201730/1575353) that [appears to be the fastest method to swap variables](https://jsperf.com/swap-array-vs-variable/9):

```
array[randomIndex] = [array[currentIndex], (array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex])][0];
```

This eliminates the need for ‘temporaryValue`.

#### Decrement operator

Decrement by one can be simplified using a [decrement operator `--`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement) - e.g. from

> ```
> currentIndex -= 1;
> ```

To:

```
currentIndex--;
```